# Multiply values extracted with a select in SQL

Tags: sql, database

Using SQL I'd like to multiply values extracted using a select:
Here an example:

```
SELECT Number1, Number2
FROM myTable
WHERE PrimaryKey = MyPrimaryKey
```

And the result for example is: `3, 4`.

Instead what I'd like to obtain is `12`.

So it's possible to make something like this?

```
SELECT Number1 * Number2
FROM myTable
WHERE PrimaryKey = MyPrimaryKey
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you got it

```
mysql> show create table numbers\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: numbers
Create Table: CREATE TABLE numbers (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'num1' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'num2' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from numbers;
+----+------+------+
| id | num1 | num2 |
+----+------+------+
|  0 |    3 |    4 |
+----+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select num1 * num2 from numbers where id = 0;
+-------------+
| num1 * num2 |
+-------------+
|          12 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I cannot try it right now on a real DB so I asked just to know if it's possible. Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
SELECT Number1 * Number2
FROM myTable
WHERE PrimaryKey = MyPrimaryKey
```